# How to get balance of a token or account for a specific timestamp?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I'm currently working in a project where I need to get balance of a token and accounts balances. I was wondering if you can retrieve the balance for yesterday or any other point in time, bot for tokens and Hbar (account balance)?

So far, I've tried to pull up all transactions for a specific timestamp to see if it includes the balance at that point of time. However the API does not return this information. Here are two queries I tried:

> https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/transactions/0.0.10918-1680795651-328812066 transaction
> https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/tokens/0.0.3332842?timestamp=1680795000 token before the transaction

Let me know how I can retrieve the balance at a specific point in time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get the total balance of a month ago by specifying timestamp like
https://mainnet-public.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/tokens/0.0.2125082/balances?timestamp=1676081399.081024708
or balance of a particular account a a month a go
https://mainnet-public.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/balances?account.id=0.0.86377&timestamp=1676081399.081024708